# Submit Site-map to for multi-store in web master in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, sitemap, google-search-console

Hello  my magento store has multi-store view for diff. language. now i need to submit sitemap for all but i am not able to submit because in magento all sitemap generate under sitemap folder and sub folders  based on store code.

its generate like that storewise http://www.demo.co.uk/sitemaps/de/sitemap.xml, other

http://www.demo.co.uk/sitemaps/uk/sitemap.xml

Any one have idea how to submit sitemap for all store in google webmaster ?

THanks in adavanc..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sitemap_index.xml file in the top magento folder. Then you can tell the crawler where to go.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
    <loc>http://demo.co.uk/sitemaps/de/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
    <loc>http://demo.co.uk/sitemaps/en/sitemap.xml</loc>
</sitemap>
```

Before you do this update the line in robots.txt to link to your index file

```
Sitemap: <sitemap_location>
```